# Error while retrieving data from OleDb database

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb

I am working on Bank project for which I have written this code
for Deposit/Withdrawal Transaction however, I am getting errors as

> Error 1   'string' does not contain a definition for 'getDouble' and no
>   extension method 'getDouble' accepting a first argument of type
>   'string' could be found
>
> Error 2   The name 'result' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I think error messages are clear. `result` is string and it does not have `getDouble` method unless you wrote an extension method.

Comment: If you are attempting to convert a string to a double value, try using the Convert.ToDouble() Method. Also you attempt to use result before it has any value: `string results;` this should also throw an exception. You can initalize it with: `string result = null;` though.

Comment: Side note: withdraw is one word, no need to capitalize the `d`

Comment: Some of that code needs to be re-thought...in `DepText_Click`, for example, you assign `balance = 0.0;`, then you assign `balance = result.getDouble`, then you assign `balance = newBalance` (which is assigned `balance + depAmount`, when `balance` was 0.0 and `depAmount` has not been assigned at all). And then YOU DO NOTHING WITH ANY OF THEM!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what Akshita2gud has presented on getting the double value from the reader when querying your data for the balance, your update command is poorly formed, and even if internal, could you be open to SQL-injection by appending strings together?  Sure thing...

The OleDB commands I have found use the "?" as a place-holder for where the parameter value coming from your activity is placed.  You have the parameter strings, but built the string based on manual entry from the screen.  You should probably have it as:

```
string update = "Update Accounts Set Balance = ? Where acctNO = ?";
```

And the parameters added in the same ordinal position as the SQL-Update above with the balance field added first, and the account number added second.  If balance is numeric, no need for strings around it as the parameter is numeric.  Similar for the account number.  If string, and the parameter is string, it knows how to handle it.  I like to prefix the parameter name so there is no ambiguity of thinking it KNOWS the column name vs what you are intending it to go into... since no named parameters in OleDB query.  I have added "p" indicating the "parameter" for balance and acctno respectively.

```
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pBalance", balance);   // balance is already numeric
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pAcctNo", AcctDep.Text);   // account # is string

df.ExecuteNonQuery();
dc.Close();
```

Apply similar SQL-Update for your deposit and withdraw statements, and fix your numeric conversion as needed, such as the proposed by Akshita2gud.

Answer (score 1):

seems you are trying to get value of balance from table. The way to do it is

```
        balance = Convert.ToInt32(df.ExecuteScalar());
```

GetDouble Method is Available with OledbDataReader(DbDataReader) and is used as

```
        OleDbDataReader dr = df.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            double val = dr.GetDouble(0);//ordinal of column
        }
```

However i suggest you to give proper naming conventions.Names like 'df' leads programmer to nowhere while debugging code as it become complex